# Trying to search a table with url api call

Tags: magento2, url, https

I need help figuring out whats is failing my search. I am new at this so if I need to rephrase something please let me know:

search 1 : (works)
https://staging.cherrydale.com/rest/default/V1/actionlog?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=participant_id -- worked

search 2 : (fails)
https://staging.cherrydale.com/rest/default/V1/participants?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=participant_id -- failed

I varified that the ID field I am using in the search is in both tables.

What I got back:

The server returned HTTP Status Code : 400 Bad Request
The response was: {"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"criteria"}}

I don't understand why it is not accepting a field name that exists.

Answer (score 0):

Why this is the answer I do not fully understand. 
I changed the "searchCriteria" to criteria. That solved the issue and now everything works correctly.

See documentation:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/performing-searches.html